# jq select value from array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file with example values:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "fileName": "FOO",
        "md5": "blablabla"
    }, {
        "fileName": "BAR",
        "md5": "alaldlafj"
    }]
}
```

Now what I want is to return the md5 value where for example the fileName is "FOO". For this I have the following statement in `jq`:

```bash
cat <file>.json | jq '.[] | select(.fileName=="FOO")'
```

However response back is: `jq: error (at <stdin>:11): Cannot index array with string "fileName"`

What is the correct way to return the md5 value where the key fileName equals a certain argument?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Found the answer:

```bash
cat <file>.json | jq -r '.files[] | select(.fileName=="FOO") | .md5'
```

Comment: Why bring `cat` into this? You can simply `jq -r '.files[] | select(.fileName=="FOO") | .md5' <file.json>`

Comment: @BrentD. - You are right that your version is shorter and simpler. However, some such as myself strongly prefer the strictly left-to-right structure that beginning with `cat` provides, especially when pipes are involved.

Comment: A shorter, simpler line that maintains strict left-to-right ordering is `<file.json jq -r '.files[] | select(.fileName=="FOO") | .md5'`

Answer (score 14):

to answer the more generic how to select value from array selecting all filenames:

```
cat results.json | jq '.files[] | .filename'
```

Comment: The question was about selecting a specific field based on value of other field. Not about selecting all the fields.

Answer (score 7):

or:

```sh
cat <file>.json | jq -r '.files[] | select(.fileName=="FOO").md5'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section to improve your answer. Can you provide an explanation for the code you have posted here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your item in the array, so do more of a filter you can do

```
cat <file>.json | jq -r '.files | map(select(.fileName=="FOO").md5)'
```

this would result in

```
['blablabla']
```